# Can I convert a telescoping antenna radio to work with an FM Dipole?

Tags: antenna, fm

I have an older FM Radio with a telescoping antenna.  Is it possible to convert that to work with an FM dipole antenna to get better reception? Such as [this one](http://amzn.com/B000EIOQBM).

Preferably without any soldering. (I'm not able to do that yet)

Here's a picture of the inside of the radio: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect one conductor of the dipole's feed line in place of the antenna on the radio. (It may be removable by a screw. If not, shorten the telescoping antenna as much as it goes and gently clamp the wire onto it instead.

The other conductor should go to the circuit ground of the radio. Try the first one of these you can find:

- A provided antenna ground terminal (GND, ⏚) is best.
- If the radio's case is metal attach it to that.
- Otherwise try other case screws. (**Avoid any other electrical connectors** like the radio's audio output; this could cause damage, especially as many “FM dipole antennas”, including the one you showed, are *folded dipoles* where there is DC continuity through the antenna.)

Listen to a weak station while you experiment to notice whether there are any results.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I cracked open the case to see if I could find the ground.  I snapped a [picture of the inside](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buogy4xc76k2yyx/inside.jpg?dl=0) .  The original antenna is at the top (and the wire had come off, so my reception is better by just putting that back.  I think that I can use the screw holding down the foil sheet as a ground right?  And [this is the antenna](http://amzn.com/B000EIOQBM) type I have, I was going to use.

Comment: @ScottCarlson Sounds like a fine plan. Please edit your question to include all of that information and use the image uploader!